# How can get return value in pipe?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have create(newItem) method which creates item on database and returns id (Observable) and getDetails(id) which returns Observable

```
import { mergeMap as _observableMergeMap, catchError as _observableCatch } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError as _observableThrow, of as _observableOf } from 'rxjs';

create(input: Input | null | undefined): Observable<number> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/create";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    const content_ = JSON.stringify(input);

    let options_ : any = {
        body: content_,
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processCreateAsync(response_);
    })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
                return this.processCreateAsync(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<number>><any>_observableThrow(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<number>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
    }));
}
```

I am trying to call create method and get id from create method and get details with this id.

```
 this._dataService.create(newItem)
            .pipe(
                switchMap( id => {
                    return this._dataService.getDetails(id);

                })
             )
            .subscribe(result => {
                // Do stuff with result
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }));
```

But I get an error which is "id is not defined" in switchMap
How can I get return value from create method and pass to getDetails method?

Comment: What is the content of `create` method?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz create item on database and return the id.

Comment: @sally I think HarunYilmaz wanted to see more source code.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz I added codes

Comment: as far as I understand, you are using a similar code as [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/eventcloud/blob/master/aspnet-core-angular/angular/src/shared/service-proxies/service-proxies.ts). If so, you are returning an `Observable` from `create` method. This is why `id` is not a value but an `Observable`.

Comment: Instead of returning `<Observable<number>>` return as `<number>` and try

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, the variable `result` in the `subscribe` should hold the value of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded rxjs to 6.2.0 and @types/node to 10.1.4 and it works now.